# Regarding logistic regression

Tags: logistic-regression

@Luke, thanks for your comments. I tried to solve by googling it but I couldn't solve the issue. here is more details about the question with an attachment of the dataset: Perform a logistic regression that regresses the column MEDVBIN on CRIM, RM, NOX, DIS and AGE. you can see the model what I used in attachment.[dataset with model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ESZo.jpg)

ValueError: endog has evaluated to an array with multiple columns that has shape (506, 2). This occurs when the variable converted to endog is non-numeric (e.g., bool or str).

looking for your kind help

Comment: Consider adding more details to your question. If you Google it, you’ll find tutorials that can explain it much better than we can in an answer here.

Comment: @Luke, thanks for your comments. I tried to solve by googling it but I couldn't solve the issue. here is more details about the question with an attachment of the dataset: Perform a logistic regression that regresses the column MEDVBIN on CRIM, RM, NOX, DIS and AGE. you can see the model what I used in attachment.

Comment: you should give the DataFrame in a Github repository and also give all the code you have tried in a Github repository

Comment: and definitely avoid a photo a screenshot is much better than a photo, press(Windows Shift S) to take it